# Splitting raster apart?

Tags: qgis, wms, contour

This is a WMS layer i'm working with:

[image]

It shows a list of various line data, 402-914.  As you can see to the right, this corresponds with various info on a topographic map.  My problem is that all I want are the contour lines, not everything else.  Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a way to separate all the different schema.  This is what the WMS page looks like:

[image]

They break it out by default into 4 different packages, each with various information, packaged similarly to the first image.  But I need just a single line (e.g., 0402), not all of them.

I'm ultimately trying to get the contour lines separate so I can create a DEM from this data.

Any suggestions?

Comment: think you need a wfs service rather than wms service to call a specific layer - where is the wms service coming from?

Comment: http://www502.regione.toscana.it/geoscopio_qg/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv?map=dbtm_rt.qgs

As far as I can tell, there is no WFS service offered.  Or at least, I can't find it.

Comment: your contours are available here https://osm-estratti.wmflabs.org/estratti/Toscana

Comment: where, mapperz?  could you link to them directly, please?  all i see is typical open streetmap data.

Comment: osm has contours available - you will struggle to extract the contours from the wms raster tiles. nmtoken has suggested that you can just pull the contours as rasters then vectorise them to vector (you need to add the height information yourself)

Answer (score 1):

As the WMS supports SLD, then you can send an SLD_BODY (or SLD) parameter in the GetMap request, to create a map image just showing the contour you want.